# Removing VLAN 1 traffic from a port

Tags: vlan

If I look at [this](https://support.citrix.com/article/CTX123489) page for Xen Server VLANs, it says

> "Configuring the XenServer management interface on a VLAN network is
> not supported"

So then the Server must be on 'VLAN1' yes, my problem is that VLAN 1 traffic is enabled untagged on all switch ports (on my tp-link switches at least), so it seems using VLAN 1 as a management port means that all this traffic is on the wire for all ports. This seems kinda derp regarding the point of VLANs

edit: who are the trolls who downvote questions without being able to answer them?

Answer (score 1):

I think there are a couple of things to understand here that might help clarify.

In a switched network, traffic will only be sent to a physical port if the destination is on that port, or it is broadcast traffic. For example if you have PC1 plugged into gi0/0, PC2 plugged into gi0/1, and PC3 plugged into gi0/2, any traffic between PC1 and PC2 will not be seen by PC3. You can test this out by plugging two computers in and running wireshark on one of them, while the other pings google. Do you see the traffic? So even if all the ports are natively set to VLAN1 (I'd be surprised if you couldn't change it), they are only going to see the data they should see.

As you stated, the XenServer documentation says VLAN is not supported for the management interface. I believe they actually mean VLAN tagging and trunked interfaces are not supported for the management interface. If you look at their example, they set the VLAN on the switch port for the management interface to be 181, meaning they set a VLAN on the port the host management interface is on, but the port is set in access mode.

Trunked ports with native VLANs have been known to cause issues with all kinds of software and hardware, so it's no surprise Citrix tell you to keep the management interface off of that configuration. Last thing you want is somebody typoing adding a VLAN to the allowed list and removing all the others causing your host to drop.

Comment: I will add as a note, I did a quick look and tp-link switches will allow you to remove an interface from vlan 1 as long as it's a member of another vlan first. The faq does say that all ports are members of vlan 1 by default, but not that you cannot remove them.

Comment: ahh yup, thanks for clarifying, so it may be a TP-Link thing. In this image https://i.imgur.com/oj4Nukw.png it shows that VLAN1 cannot be selected to remove untagged ports. In my case I am using an intel NUC with Xen, with only 1 internal NIC. This issue arose actually when I was trying to troubleshoot a VLAN which had a Xen VM on it, where I noticed traffic from the management LAN on the wire.. perhaps there is no easy solution for this, besides VLAN hosts have a VLAN VPID which I believe prevents them from connecting into to VLAN1